# RegEx Confusion in linux shell script

Tags: regex, linux, shell

Can someone explain what this does in a linux shell.....

```
port=$((${devpath##*[-.]} - 1))
```

I have a variable named `$devpath`, and one possible value is `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/2-1`.

I'm assuming that ${devpath##*[-.]} performs some sort of regex on $devpath, but it makes no sense to me. Nor does *[-.] which I understand to mean "one of more of any one of the character '-' or any other character except newline"

When running through a script (this is from [usb-devices.sh](https://github.com/gregkh/usbutils/blob/master/usb-devices#L104)), it seems that the value of port is always the first numeric digit. Something else that confuses me is the '-1' at the end, shouldn't that reduce whatever `${devpath##*[-.]}` does by one?

I tried looking up regex in shell expressions but nothing made any sense and no where could I find an explanation for `##`.

Comment: How are we supposed to know without looking at your whole script??

Answer (score 5):

There is no regex here. `${var##pattern}` returns the value of `var` with any match on `pattern` removed from the prefix (but this is a glob pattern, not a regex); `$((value - 1))` subtracts one from `value`. So the expression takes the number after the last dash or dot and reduces it by one.

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and [Arithmetic Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) in the Bash manual.

Answer (score 5):

Given the variable:

```
r="/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/2-123.45"
```

`echo ${r##*-}` returns `123.45` and `echo ${r##*[-.]}` returns `45`. Do you see the pattern here?

Let's go a bit further: the expression `${string##substring}` strips the longest match of `$substring` from the front of `$string`.

So with `${r##*[-.]}` we are stripping everything in `$r` until the last `-` or `.` is found.

Then, `$(( ))` is used for arithmetic expressions. Thus, with `$(( $var - 1 ))` you are subtracting `1` from the value coming from `${r##*[-.]}`.

All together, `port=$((${devpath##*[-.]} - 1))` means: store in `$port` the value of the last number after either `-` or `.` at the end of `$devpath`.

Following the example below, `echo $((${r##*[-.]} - 1))` returns `44` (45 - 1).

Comment: To complete, all these syntaxes are described here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html (in the *Substring Removal* part)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte sure, only that I would recommend going through the original source: [Bash reference manual #Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).